# Not getting notificatiom for deleting an instance of a recurring event

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am getting delete [change notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0)! when deleting a recurring event as a whole. However, I am not getting a delete notification when deleting a single instance of a recurring event. Is this by design?